# Conversion from table to tree menu in C# for asp.net using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, menu, tree

I have the table like, below

```
Rowid   SportID SportDesc   CategoryID  CatPlace    TourID  TourName
13  5   Tennis      785     ITF Men     59075   USA F13, Singles
14  5   Tennis      785     ITF Men     59076   USA F13, Doubles
15  5   Tennis      213     ITF Women   59097   Istanbul, Doubles W-WITF-TUR-14A
16  5   Tennis      213     ITF Women   59100   Santa Margherita Di Pula, Doubles W-WITF-
17  5   Tennis      213     ITF Women   59120   Indian Harbour Beach, Singles W-WITF-USA-10A
18  5   Tennis      213     ITF Women   59121   Indian Harbour Beach, Doubles W-WITF-USA-10A
1   1   Soccer      19      Finland     527 Ykkonen
2   1   Soccer      21      Russia      6353    Premier League, Women
6   1   Soccer      13      Brazil      55510   Baiano, 1 Divisao, Playoffs
7   1   Soccer      13      Brazil      55980   Mineiro, Modulo I, Playoffs
8   1   Soccer      565     Kosovo      56570   Kosovo FA Cup
3   6   Handball    302     Russia      22634   Super League, Playoffs
4   6   Handball    302     Russia      22636   Super League, Relegation round
5   6   Handball    302     Russia      29580   Super League, Women, Relegation Round
19  21  Cricket     105     International   59149   ODI Series England vs. Ireland
9   31  Badminton   259     International   59053   OUE Singapore Open (SS) 2017
10  31  Badminton   259     International   59054   OUE Singapore Open (SS) 2017, Doubles
11  31  Badminton   259     International   59056   OUE Singapore Open (SS) 2017, Women
12  31  Badminton   259     International   59057   OUE Singapore Open (SS) 2017, Women Doubles
```

and the format I want

- Soccer

    Finland
      Ykkonen

    Russia
      Baiano, 1 Divisao, Playoffs

    Brazil
      Super League, Relegation round
      Mineiro, Modulo I, Playoffs

    Kosovo
      Kosovo FA Cup
- Tennis
- Handball
- Cricket
- Badminton

like tree menu format for menubar, I written code is,

menu class

```
public class newMenuData
        {
            public string Row_id { get; set; }
            public string parent_id { get; set; }
            public string CountryID { get; set; }
            public string EventMID { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string EventMDesc { get; set; }

            //added
            public string sportsdesc { get; set; }
}
```

and the main code

```
DataSet dtresult = new DataSet();

                    List<newMenuData> lstAllMenus = new List<newMenuData>();

                    dtresult = PObj.ExecuteSPDSwithoutparameter("Get_County");
                    if (dtresult.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dtresult.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            lstAllMenus.Add(new newMenuData
                            {

                                Row_id = dtresult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Rowid"].ToString(),
                                parent_id = dtresult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SportID"].ToString(),
                                sportsdesc = dtresult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SportDesc"].ToString(),
                                CountryID = dtresult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CategoryID"].ToString(),
                                EventMID = dtresult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TourID"].ToString(),
                                Country = dtresult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CatPlace"].ToString(),
                                EventMDesc = dtresult.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TourName"].ToString()
                            });
                        }


                    }
                    string Divmenu = "";
            Divmenu += "<div id='cssmenu'><ul>";

            for (int i = 0; i < lstAllMenus.Count; i++)
            {
    //for checking soccer sports only
                if (lstAllMenus[i].parent_id == "1")
                {

                    // Menu Header

                    if (lstAllMenus.Where(x => x.parent_id == lstAllMenus[i].Row_id).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        Divmenu += "\n<li><span>" + lstAllMenus[i].sportsdesc + "</span></li>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Divmenu += "\n<li class='active has-sub'><span>" + lstAllMenus[i].sportsdesc + "</span><ul>";


                        // subMenu 1

                        foreach (newMenuData sub1 in lstAllMenus.Where(x => x.parent_id == lstAllMenus[i].Row_id))
                        {


                            if (lstAllMenus.Where(x => x.parent_id == sub1.Row_id).Count() == 0)
                            {
                                Divmenu += "\n\t<li><a href='#'><span>" + sub1.Country + "</span></a></li>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Divmenu += "\n\t<li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>" + sub1.Country + "</span></a><ul>";


                                // subMenu 2

                                foreach (newMenuData sub2 in lstAllMenus.Where(x => x.parent_id == "1"))
                                {

                                    if (lstAllMenus.Where(x => x.parent_id == sub2.Row_id).Count() == 0)
                                    {
                                        Divmenu += "\n\t\t<li><span>" + sub2.EventMDesc + "</span></li>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Divmenu += "\n\t\t<li class='active has-sub'><span>" + sub2.EventMDesc + "</span><ul>";
                                        Divmenu += "\n\t\t\t</ul></li>";
                                    }


                                }
                                Divmenu += "\n\t</ul></li>";


                            }


                        }
                        Divmenu += "\n</ul></li>";

                    }



                }

            }
            Divmenu += "</ul></div>";
```

my output is,

```html
<div id='cssmenu'><ul>
<li class='active has-sub'><span>Soccer</span><ul>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Finland</span></a><ul>
  <li class='active has-sub'><span>Ykkonen</span><ul>
   </ul></li>
  <li><span>Premier League, Women</span></li>
  <li class='active has-sub'><span>Baiano, 1 Divisao, Playoffs</span><ul>
   </ul></li>
  <li><span>Mineiro, Modulo I, Playoffs</span></li>
  <li><span>Kosovo FA Cup</span></li>
 </ul></li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>Russia</span></a></li>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Brazil</span></a><ul>
  <li class='active has-sub'><span>Ykkonen</span><ul>
   </ul></li>
  <li><span>Premier League, Women</span></li>
  <li class='active has-sub'><span>Baiano, 1 Divisao, Playoffs</span><ul>
   </ul></li>
  <li><span>Mineiro, Modulo I, Playoffs</span></li>
  <li><span>Kosovo FA Cup</span></li>
 </ul></li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>Brazil</span></a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>Kosovo</span></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><span>Soccer</span></li>
<li class='active has-sub'><span>Soccer</span><ul>
 <li><a href='#'><span>Russia</span></a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>Russia</span></a></li>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Russia</span></a><ul>
  <li class='active has-sub'><span>Ykkonen</span><ul>
   </ul></li>
  <li><span>Premier League, Women</span></li>
  <li class='active has-sub'><span>Baiano, 1 Divisao, Playoffs</span><ul>
   </ul></li>
  <li><span>Mineiro, Modulo I, Playoffs</span></li>
  <li><span>Kosovo FA Cup</span></li>
 </ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><span>Soccer</span></li>
<li><span>Soccer</span></li></ul></div>
```

kindly give the solution...in C#

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is the problem you are facing? You get an exception?

Comment: i add the screeshot of my output...

Comment: I still don't get your question, besides that you want us to provide some magic code. You talk about Linq, but I don't see linq in your code.